# Machine specific layers in yocto

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want to add some layers fetch from upstream for a new machine (call it A) mainly just to use the machine A configure file, kernel and u-boot provided from those layers. However, the new layers have several bbappend files (with bb files as well) that the version is different with other machines' layers in my yocto project.

For example, **machine A** has its own **gstreamer1.0_1.8.1.bb** and bbappend file. **Other machines** are using **gstreamer1.0_1.6.1.bb**. What happens when I build the image for the other machine is that it builds the version 1.8.1 because Yocto will always look for the newest compatible version of package and build it. However, the gstreamer1.0_1.8.1.bbappend file is written specifically for machine A, does not apply to others and causing errors. Not only the gstreamer, there are more.

I got an idea like `BBLAYERS_A += "new_layers \ ..."` in the bblayers.conf file, but unfortunately it does not work the way I want it to.

Another idea I have is like:

```
BBMASK_B = "new_layers \ ..."
BBMASK_C = "new_layers \ ..."
BBMASK_D = "new_layers \ ..."
BBMASK_E = "new_layers \ ..."
BBMASK_F = "new_layers \ ..."
BBMASK_G = "new_layers \ ..."
BBMASK_H = "new_layers \ ..."
BBMASK_I = "new_layers \ ..."
...
```

It doesn't look good to me and I doubt it won't work as well. I think the build procedure is to load the bblayers.conf file first, then the local.conf. Therefore, before knowing what machine it is going to build, the layers are deployed.

My question is how can I make those newly added layers that work with **machine A** only, but won't get used by the **other machines**.

Answer (score 2):

You should try to make a BSP-layer to only cause any effects if any of the machines in that layer is being used.

In your example, `gstreamer1.0_1.8.1.bb`, you should add

```
COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "^machinea$"
```

note, it's a regular expression, so by omitting the leading `^` and ending `$`, you can by mistake match similar named machines.

Also note, I changed your example of machine name `A` to `machinea`, as machines needs to be small letters.

If you're adding `.bbappend` files, you typically have them modify the build by eg.

```
SOME_VAR_machinea
```

If you're overriding files, you typically put them in a structure like:

```
recipes-support/myrecipe/myrecipe/machinea/some-file
```

In this case, note the extra subdirectory `machinea`, which will ensure that `some-file` is only being used for that particular machine.

Comment: The COMPATIBLE_MACHINE makes sense. However, my apologies, my case is most of the layers (not only for the machinea) are fetching from upstream (I modified the question a bit) and I don't want to change the upstream bbappend files locally. How could I achieve it? Is there like the local.conf that I can make changes globally instead of modifying files in layers?

Comment: Well, are the layers generic layers, although you want them to apply to only a single machine? Or are they machine specific layers, ie are the upstreams claimed to be machine specific layers?

Answer (score 1):

The solution that works for me is to use [DISTRO](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#distro-layer) feature from yocto. It is flexible. What I did is to use different `DISTRO` for `machine_A` (meaning using a different configuration file for A), then include a `MACHINE_A.inc` with `BBMASK = ""` (or `BBMASK = "layers that not for A"`).

In the default Poky `DISTRO`, inside the bblayers.conf file, I block all layers introduced by `machine_A` by using `BBMASK = "all machine_A's layers"`.

In the local.conf, I set `DISTRO_machine_A = "MACHINE_A"`, so when building the image for `machine_A`, bitbake will look into `DISTRO` and find the configuration file for `machine_A`, which will reset the global `BBMASK` to enable layers for `machine_A` itself (or even to block other layers).

By using `DISTRO`, I am able to get a separate build environment for different machines while introducing new layers into the project. Kind of like `BBMASK_machine_A` (`BBMASK_machine_A` won't actually work as my question described).